# Binding a TextBox to a ListBox in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a MainWindow with a TextBox and a Listbox. The TextBox is bound two-way to a ListBox, which ist populated from a BindingList.

```
InitializeComponent();
productNames = new BindingList<string>(/*some content*/);

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem");
binding.ElementName = "listBox1";

textBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

listBox1.ItemsSource = productNames;
```

So far, so good: The ListBox displays the content of my list nicely, and the TextBox dutifully displays any item that is selected in the ListBox. however, when I type some Text in the Textbox, the corresponding item in the ListBox does not change.

I googled a lot concerning UpdateSourceTrigger, binding, etc., but almost all of it is about using XAML, and nothing I found fits the bill. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting `binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;` in code behind?

Comment: I have. It didn't do the trick. I think the answers by Peter and unkreativ explained why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because you are binding to a string. So there is no INotifyPropertyChanged-events fired and so the list does not noticed it got updated. Try to bind the list to some complex object with a string:

```
class CompexObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string myString;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string MyString
    {
        get { return this.myString; }
        set
        {
            this.myString = value;
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyString)));
        }
    }
}
```

And then set your list like:

```
 productNames = new BindingList<ComplexObject>(/*some content*/);
```

Your binding should change to:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem.MyString");
binding.ElementName = "listBox1";

textBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This does exactly what I head in mind - with one slight flaw; adding the objects to the list will result in having the type of the object displayed in the listbox itself instead of the String that I intended.
Luckiliy, that is easily fixed by adding 
`listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "MyString";`

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you dont tell your UI that the string has changed. You can do this with this interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149863/how-to-write-viewmodelbase-in-mvvm-wpf) if you are interested and maybe get into `MVVM`.

**But for a simple solution in the code behind i would recommend dependency propertys and Bindings in `XAML` like in this example.**

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Name="myWindow">
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=ItemCollection, Mode=OneWay}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">


    </ListBox>


    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=TextBoxText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace Test
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Store your ListBox entrys here
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<string> ItemCollection
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemCollectionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemCollectionProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemCollection.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemCollectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>()));


        /// <summary>
        /// This binds to the TextBox text
        /// </summary>
        public string TextBoxText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TextBoxText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxText", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnTextBoxTextChanged));

        private static void OnTextBoxTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            MainWindow self = d as MainWindow;

            if(self != null)
            {
                self.OnTextBoxTextChanged(args.NewValue.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(string newValue)
        {
            if (this.ItemCollection.Contains(newValue))
            {
                this.SelectedItem = newValue;
            }
            else
            {
                this.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This binds to the selected item of your ListBox
        /// </summary>
        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnSelectedItemChanged));

        private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            MainWindow self = d as MainWindow;

            if (self != null)
            {
                self.OnSelectedItemChanged(args.NewValue as string);
            }
        }

        private void OnSelectedItemChanged(string newValue)
        {
            if (!this.TextBoxText.Equals(newValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue))
            {
                this.TextBoxText = newValue;
            }
        }


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ItemCollection.Add("Name 1");
            this.ItemCollection.Add("Name 2");
            this.ItemCollection.Add("Name 3");
            this.ItemCollection.Add("Name 4");
            this.ItemCollection.Add("Name 5");

        }

    }
}
```

It also unselects the `ListBox` entry when the `TextBox` text doesn't match an item from the 'ItemsSource' of the `ListBox`.

EDIT: More Comments