# How to reduce boilerplate code for numerous combobox.selecteditem properties

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a view with a large number of `ComboBox` controls which can be populated with a Yes/No option.

I use this to enter some data into the database.

At the moment, to bind all of these combobox selected items I have to do this boilerplate code in my ViewModel for every combobox `SelectedItem`:

```cs
private string _YesNo1;
public string YesNo1
{
    get { return _YesNo1; }
    set
    {
        _YesNo1= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("YesNo1");
    }
}
```

With my view I'd need to do this code some 15+ times and bind each one in XAML.

Is there a better way I can do this so I can bind each combobox `SelectedItem` separately but avoid this repeated code?

Comment: This sounds like something that'd be more suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since it's working code that you would like to improve.

Comment: Be careful with solutions that are “too clever” (like looping a number of controls). While it might save you a bit of time in the beginning, you risk ending up with something that’s difficult to both understand and change...

Comment: @Noceo A good tip. Ordinarily I'd be happy writing longer but clearer code but in this case, it's just a lot of repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are few options.

1. Make a base class which will implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36151255/8212196). It will reduce a little bit code.
2. There is a library Fody which has a plugin [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged). It generates code during compilation, which adds code related with `INotifyPropoertyChanged`.

Comment: `PropertyChanged.Fody` looks like exactly what I need. Thanks.