Problem with my MVVM , i cant change props a ViewModel from another ViewModel ,UI is not updating
Im have many issues regarding my MVVM's, i cant pass any props or if i still pass them from a ViewModel to another ViewModel its still not updating the UI.
For example here :
My xaml files :
<UserControl.DataContext>
  <viewModels:PlotViewModel  />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Border Grid.Row="0">
            <oxy:PlotView Name="SpectralPlot"
                          Width="Auto"
                          Height="Auto"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Background="Transparent"
                          Model="{Binding SpectralPlotModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          Visibility="{Binding IsSpectralPlotVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="0">
            <oxy:PlotView Name="SpectralAEPlot"
                          Width="Auto"
                          Height="Auto"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Background="Transparent"
                          Model="{Binding SpectralAEPlotModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          Visibility="{Binding IsSpectralAEPlotVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Border>


<UserControl.DataContext>
  <viewModels:AEViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<!-- Lock -->
<Button Content="Back to Plot"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"
        Width="170"
        Height="45"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Visibility="{Binding GoBackButtonVisibility}"
        Command="{Binding GoBackCommand,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Button Content="Lock"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"
        Width="170"
        Height="45"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Visibility="{Binding LockButtonVisibility}"
        Command="{Binding LockCommand,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

My ViewModel classes :
namespace InteWPF.ViewModel.Components
{
    public class PlotViewModel : ObservableObject, IDisposable
    {
        // ====================== About Plot ======================
        private DispatcherTimer _timer;
        private bool _isTracking;
        private bool _isPaused;
        private bool _locked = false;
        private bool _stopAll = false;
        private bool _isLocked = false;
        private DataPoint _nearestPoint = new DataPoint(0,0);
        private DataPoint near = new DataPoint(0, 0);
        private ScreenPoint mouseDownPoint;
        private int waveLengthIndex;
        private bool mouseWavelengthClick = false;

        public PlotViewModel()
        {
            SpectralPlotModel = new PlotModel
            {
                Title = "Sweep",
                Background = OxyColors.Transparent,
                TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.White
            };

            SpectralPlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                Title = "Wavelength",
                TitleColor = OxyColors.White,
                AxislineColor = OxyColors.White,
                TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                TicklineColor = OxyColors.White,
                StringFormat = "0.###",
                Minimum = 1546,
                Maximum = 1558
            });

            SpectralPlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Left,
                Title = "Arbitrary Units",
                TitleColor = OxyColors.White,
                AxislineColor = OxyColors.White,
                TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                TicklineColor = OxyColors.White,
                StringFormat = "0.###",
                Minimum = 0,
                Maximum = 5,
            });

            SpectralPlotModel.Series.Add(new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Data",
                Color = OxyColors.White,
                MarkerFill = OxyColors.White,
                MarkerType = MarkerType.None,
                LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
                StrokeThickness = 2,
            });

            SpectralPlotModel.MouseDown += MyPlotModel_MouseDown;

            SpectralAEPlotModel = new PlotModel
            {
                Title = "AE",
                Background = OxyColors.Transparent,
                TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.White
            };

            SpectralAEPlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                Title = "Time",
                TitleColor = OxyColors.White,
                AxislineColor = OxyColors.White,
                TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                TicklineColor = OxyColors.White,
                StringFormat = "0.###",
            });

            SpectralAEPlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Left,
                Title = "Amplitude",
                TitleColor = OxyColors.White,
                AxislineColor = OxyColors.White,
                TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                TicklineColor = OxyColors.White,
                StringFormat = "0.###",
            });

            SpectralAEPlotModel.Series.Add(new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "AE Data",
                Color = OxyColors.White,
                MarkerFill = OxyColors.White,
                MarkerType = MarkerType.None,
                LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
                StrokeThickness = 2,
            });
            // ====================== Commands ======================
            ScanCommand = new RelayCommand(o => ExecuteScan());
            PauseCommand = new RelayCommand(o => ExecutePause());
            SaveSpectrumCommand = new RelayCommand(o => ExecuteSaveSpectrum());
            SavePngCommand = new RelayCommand(o => ExecuteSavePng());
            SettingsCommand = new RelayCommand(o => ExecuteSettings());
            LockCommand = new RelayCommand(o => OnLockChanged(0,0));
            GoBackCommand = new RelayCommand(o => OnGoBackChanged());
        }       

        private void MyPlotModel_MouseDown(object sender, OxyMouseDownEventArgs ex)
        {
            //mouseWavelengthClick = true;
            OxyPlot.ElementCollection<OxyPlot.Axes.Axis> axisList = SpectralPlotModel.Axes;

            Axis xAxis = axisList.FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Position == AxisPosition.Bottom);
            Axis yAxis = axisList.FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Position == AxisPosition.Left);

            NearestPoint = OxyPlot.Axes.Axis.InverseTransform(ex.Position, xAxis, yAxis);
            //Debug.Print("Nearest Point: " + NearestPoint);
        }


        public async void OnLockChanged(int scanWindow, int intesityThreshold)
        {
            //Debug.Print("Wavelength Index: "+waveLengthIndex);
            //Debug.Print($"Points: {NearestPoint}, scanWindowSeconds: {scanWindow},Threshold: {intesityThreshold}");
            Debug.Print("Lock ..!");
            Debug.Print("IsSpectralPlotVisible: "+ IsSpectralPlotVisible);
            Debug.Print("IsSpectralAEPlotVisible: " + IsSpectralAEPlotVisible);
            //IsSpectralPlotVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
            //IsSpectralAEPlotVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            Debug.Print("IsSpectralPlotVisible: " + IsSpectralPlotVisible);
            Debug.Print("IsSpectralAEPlotVisible: " + IsSpectralAEPlotVisible);
            await AEHTTP.SendAEValues(new DataPoint(1552,0.4), scanWindow, intesityThreshold);
            await UpdateAEPlotAsync(IP, 4004);
        }


        public async void OnGoBackChanged()
        {
            Debug.Print("Go Back ..!");
            Debug.Print("IsSpectralPlotVisible: " + IsSpectralPlotVisible);
            Debug.Print("IsSpectralAEPlotVisible: " + IsSpectralAEPlotVisible);
            //IsSpectralPlotVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            //IsSpectralAEPlotVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Debug.Print("IsSpectralPlotVisible: " + IsSpectralPlotVisible);
            Debug.Print("IsSpectralAEPlotVisible: " + IsSpectralAEPlotVisible);
        }
       
        // ====================== Getters Setters ======================
        // ====================== Commands ======================
        public ICommand ScanCommand { get; }
        public ICommand PauseCommand { get; }
        public ICommand SaveSpectrumCommand { get; }
        public ICommand SavePngCommand { get; }
        public ICommand SettingsCommand { get; }
        public ICommand LockCommand { get; }
        public ICommand GoBackCommand { get; }
        // ====================== Plotters ======================
        public PlotModel SpectralPlotModel { get; set; }
        public PlotModel SpectralAEPlotModel { get; set; }
        // ====================== About Nearest Point Visibility ======================
        public DataPoint NearestPoint
        {
            get
            {
                Debug.Print($"Entered Get {_nearestPoint}!!!"); 
                return _nearestPoint; 
            }
            set
            {
                Debug.Print($"Entered Set {value}!!!");
                _nearestPoint = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NearestPoint));
             }
        }
        // ====================== About Plot Visibility ======================
        public Visibility IsSpectralPlotVisible { get; set; }
        public Visibility IsSpectralAEPlotVisible { get; set; }

        //private Visibility _isSpectralPlotVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        //private Visibility _isSpectralAEPlotVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        //public Visibility IsSpectralPlotVisible
        //{
        //    get => _isSpectralPlotVisible;
        //    set
        //    {
        //            _isSpectralPlotVisible = value;
        //            OnPropertyChanged();
        //    }
        //}
        //public Visibility IsSpectralAEPlotVisible
        //{
        //    get => _isSpectralAEPlotVisible;
        //    set
        //    {
        //            _isSpectralAEPlotVisible = value;
        //            OnPropertyChanged();
        //    }
        //}


namespace InteWPF.ViewModel.Screens
{
    public class AEViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        // Variables
        private PlotViewModel _plotViewModel { get; set; }

        private bool _isLocked;
        private int _scanWindow;
        private int _intesityThreshold;


        private Visibility _goBackButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        private Visibility _lockButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        public Visibility GoBackButtonVisibility
        {
            get => _goBackButtonVisibility;
            set
            {
                _goBackButtonVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public Visibility LockButtonVisibility
        {
            get => _lockButtonVisibility;
            set
            {
                _lockButtonVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public AEViewModel () 
        {
            _plotViewModel = new PlotViewModel();
            LockCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteLockCommand);
            GoBackCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteGoBackCommand);
        }

        public int ScanWindow
        {
            get => _scanWindow;
            set
            {
                if (_scanWindow != value)
                {
                    _scanWindow = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public int IntesityThreshold
        {
            get => _intesityThreshold;
            set
            {
                if (_intesityThreshold != value)
                {
                    _intesityThreshold = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        //ICommand
        public ICommand LockCommand { get; }
        public ICommand GoBackCommand { get; }
        private void ExecuteLockCommand(object parameter)
        {
            _plotViewModel.OnLockChanged(_scanWindow, _intesityThreshold);
            _plotViewModel.IsSpectralPlotVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _plotViewModel.IsSpectralAEPlotVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            GoBackButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            LockButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        private void ExecuteGoBackCommand(object parameter)
        {
            _plotViewModel.OnGoBackChanged();
            _plotViewModel.IsSpectralPlotVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            _plotViewModel.IsSpectralAEPlotVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
            GoBackButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            LockButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}

I cant hide - collapse my second plot , i want when the user clicks on Lock Button to hide the First Plot and Show the Second One ,and if the user press the GoBack Button to do the opposite.
I think its a problem with my MVVM architecture or somethings wrong with the async ?  Because when i try also to pass NearestPoint with MyPlotModel_MouseDown function i cant get the value to OnLockChanged Function also in order to use it.
Any help will be appreciate . Thanks !
Edit :
This is how my xaml.cs files are calling my View Model files :
namespace InteWPF.View.Components

{
    public partial class Plot : UserControl
    {
        public Plot()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new PlotViewModel();
        }
    }
}


namespace Inte.View.Screens
{
    public partial class AE : UserControl
    {
        public AE()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new AEViewModel();
        }

    }
}

Main :
namespace InteWPF.ViewModel
{

    class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        // Relay Commands
        public RelayCommand HCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand AECommand { get; set; }

        // ViewModels
        public HomeViewModel Home { get; set; }
        public AEViewModel AcousticEmission { get; set; }


        private object _currentView;
        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                if (_currentView != value)
                {
                    _currentView = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public MainViewModel()
        {
            //Import the Screens 
            Home = new HomeViewModel {};
            AcousticEmission = new AEViewModel {};

            //By Default
            CurrentView = Home;
            //Commands
            HCommand = new RelayCommand((o) =>
            {
                CurrentView = Home;
                Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = new Home {};
            });

            AECommand = new RelayCommand((o) =>
            {
                CurrentView = AcousticEmission;
                Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = new AcousticEmission {};
            });

        }
    }
}



I can see also my values change but the plot is not collapsing or appearing :
Lock ..!
IsSpectralPlotVisible: Visible
IsSpectralAEPlotVisible: Collapsed
IsSpectralPlotVisible: Collapsed
IsSpectralAEPlotVisible: Visible
Go Back ..!
IsSpectralPlotVisible: Collapsed
IsSpectralAEPlotVisible: Visible
IsSpectralPlotVisible: Visible
IsSpectralAEPlotVisible: Collapsed


It would be better to extract failing part of the code into minimal, reproducible example or at least specify exactly what part is not working..

Yiep i delete a lot of code already , its only 3-4 variables that maybe dont need i will delete them . The issue is that i want to change plots when i press the Lock button and if i press the goBack button to change them from hidden to vissible again and go back to the first plot  . The main issue is that i do this action from another ViewModel so i dont know where exactly is the issue.  I get the variable values correctly in my second ViewModel so there is something wrong with UI trigger.(when i switch from visible collapse etc)

I looked through your Github link and noticed you have nested namespaces. If you break out each class into it's own .cs file instead of loading up your mainwindow.xaml.cs with several namespaces and classes then it may clear things up.

It's an excellent point. What I was doing here is attempting to create the same hierarchy that OP has in their posted code. Definitely this amounts to "picking a poison" but I'll think about what you're saying, thx!

In order for the interface to change when a property changes, it must know about it. Simply changing a variable won't do anything. Use SetProperty to notify the interface that a property value has changed:
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public class PlotViewModel : ObservableObject, IDisposable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private Visibility isSpectralPlotVisible;
    private Visibility isSpectralAEPlotVisible;

    public Visibility IsSpectralPlotVisible
    {
        get => isSpectralPlotVisible;
        set => SetProperty(ref isSpectralPlotVisible, value);
    }
    public Visibility IsSpectralAEPlotVisible
    {
        get => isSpectralAEPlotVisible;
        set => SetProperty(ref isSpectralAEPlotVisible, value);
    }

In an ideal situation, you would use a ViewModelBase, in which you would define the SetField method as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36151255/24939885

Hello and thanks for the response, i already call ObservableObject where inside there i trigger UI events with INotifyPropertyChanged (its the same code as the one you send me above). I tried your code also but it didin't work sadly ... i dont know whats the issue i've been trying for 2 days and i cant find it.

Yes, it's my mistake. But you still have an error in assigning properties: use set => SetProperty(ref prop, value). I have corrected the proposed code so that it is correct

I dont know im not still able to fix it .. i post my xaml.cs files also maybe i have messed up with the MVVM architecture somehow ...

Just ObservableObject doesn't observale propertyes. Use set => SetProperty(); instead set;

I tried this also but nothing still .. the funny thing is that i can see from Debug.Print the value that its changing but the plot it does not appear-disappear .

The way that you have it coded now your properties do not notify at all. When you say "there is something wrong with UI trigger" this is what's wrong.
I spotted two issues regarding your use of ObservableObject. The first is that you now need a partial declaration on the class. The second is that you need to add the [ObservableProperty] to the private fields you've declared.
This will allow the ObservableObject to generate properties that will now raise PropertyChanged when a new value is set to the property.
namespace InteWPF.ViewModel.Screens
{
    // Requires partial class declaration
    public partial class AEViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        // Requires [ObservableProperty] attribute
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Visibility _goBackButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Visibility _lockButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        .
        .
        .
        // Do the same unto others...
    }
}

In the same way, these don't notify at all:
    // ====================== About Plot Visibility ======================
    public Visibility IsSpectralPlotVisible { get; set; }
    public Visibility IsSpectralAEPlotVisible { get; set; }

The same changes need to go on them as well:
public partial class PlotViewModel : ObservableObject, IDisposable
{
    // ====================== About Plot Visibility ======================
    [ObservableProperty] // Will generate IsSpectralPlotVisible member
    private Visibility _isSpectralPlotVisible;

    [ObservableProperty] // Will generate IsSpectralAEPlotVisible member
    private Visibility _isSpectralAEPlotVisible;
    .
    .
    .
}

That's a lot of code you got there, but I believe I've "covered the bases" now. Try making these changes and see if it helps your issue.

For some reason i get this error :
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error (active) MVVMTK0019 The field InterrogatorWPF.ViewModel.Components.PlotViewModel._isSpectralPlotVisible cannot be used to generate an observable property, as its containing type doesn't inherit from ObservableObject, nor does it use [ObservableObject] or [INotifyPropertyChanged] (https://aka.ms/mvvmtoolkit/errors/mvvmtk0019) 


I've posted to my GitHub a very minimal example you can Browse or Clone and run. If it turns out being more helpful than this answer, let me know and I'll post that solution instead.

Im confused ... i think i messed up with my MVVM i paste the xaml.cs files maybe this help ... also i created a MainViewModel for my Screens ... im new in this framework so i dont know if i messed this up ,i followed some youtube videos and they said to created 2 files 1->Observable object and 2->RelayCommands in order to navigate and make my MVVM architecture to work . Thank you very much for your effort, i really appreciate it but i think i must change all of my app in order for this to work ... i need to find a workaround for that specific problem . i WIll post my main also .

But did you download and run my GitHub sample? I tried to make it super-simple and have it address your specific uses case: an OxyPlot user control that is nested in a MainWindow. Your code is not that far off! But you need to put your properties in the correct format needed by ObservableObject so that it can make things easier for you. And, BTW, my code is much closer to what we mean when we ask you to edit your question down to a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Say, I've been doing this a few decades, I'd just like to encourage you instead of spending all day today trying to copy-paste from all the great tutorials out there, just take a few hours to "read the owners manual", that is, the Documentation for ObservableObject so that you actually understand it. And then if I may offer this, take a few deep breaths because we've all had that sense of "mild panic" when being faced with some new coding method to learn!

Yiep the example working perfect !
The thing is that i use a seperate class for my ViewModels and im not inside xaml.cs i think if i move them it will work but my mind is messed up from morning i try to find a solution without destorying my entire app logic.I found many turtorials but every one of them have a "different approach" i started with navigation and all recommended MVVM and now im in a dead end with my state management logic....im frustrated....

I will try to read it but i dont believe it will change anything ,i think something wrong with my sharing variables between ViewModels in total.
